# The Quranic Quintet

Tags: gods, arabic, islam

There are a number of pre-Islamic deities mentioned in the Quran. Five particular deities are often grouped together (maybe always, I'm not sure): [Wadd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wadd), [Suwa'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suwa%27), [Yaghuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yagh%C5%ABth), [Ya'uq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ya%27uq) and [Nasr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasr_(deity)). Save for Wadd, who according to Wikipedia was a lunar deity and Nasr who might have been a sun deity, it isn't stated there what these deities were gods of. Is it known what they represented/what their dominion was as deities? Or are there commonly-accepted theories?